# Using comma delimited values from a dataframe in hsv()

Tags: r

This question is related to the one I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941878).  I'm trying to color individual points in a scatterplot with a color specified in a column of the dataframe.  The data is from a tab delimited file and looks like this:

```
> dput(ztestHSV)
structure(list(y = c(0, -1, -1, -2), x = c(0, 2, 0, -2), group = c("m", 
"m", "m", "s"), colorHSV = c("0.02,0.83,0.89", "0.59,0.59,0.85", 
"0.25,0.45,0.8", "0.55,0.41,0.8"), colorText = c("red", "blue", 
"green", "turquoise")), .Names = c("y", "x", "group", "colorHSV", 
"colorText"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

i.e.

```
   y  x group  colorHSV       colorText
1  0  0     m  0.02,0.83,0.89       red
2 -1  2     m  0.59,0.59,0.85      blue
3 -1  0     m  0.25,0.45,0.8      green
4 -2 -2     s  0.55,0.41,0.8  turquoise
```

The following code works well for the predefined set of colors available in R:

```
ztestHSV=read.table(file="testHSV.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE,
                    colClasses=c("numeric","numeric","character","character","character"))

plot(ztestHSV[ztestHSV$group=='m',]$x,ztestHSV[ztestHSV$group=='m',]$y,type='n')
points(ztestHSV[ztestHSV$group=='m',]$x,ztestHSV[ztestHSV$group=='m',]$y,
       pch=23,cex=1.5,
       bg=ztestHSV[ztestHSV$group=='m',]$colorText
)
```

What I would really like to do is use `hsv()` to specify the colors.  But I can't figure out the right `bg` command to make it work.  I've tried several things and listed them below with the associated result.

1

```
bg=hsv(as.numeric(ztestHSV$colorHSV))

Error in hsv(as.numeric(ztestHSV$colorHSV)) : 
bad hsv to rgb color conversion
In addition: Warning message:
In hsv(as.numeric(ztestHSV$colorHSV)) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

2

```
bg=hsv(as.numeric(strsplit(ztestHSV$colorHSV,",")))

Error in hsv(as.numeric(strsplit(ztestHSV$colorHSV, ","))) : 
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

3

```
bg=hsv(unlist(strsplit(ztestHSV$colorHSV,",")))
```

Above runs but uses the wrong background colors

4

```
bg=hsv(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(ztestHSV$colorHSV,","))))
```

Above doesn't generate an error but doesn't fill background colors

It seems like this is a problem with converting the character string of colorHSV to something that `hsv()` can use, but I don't know how to do it.  Any help would be great.

Comment: In the future, it would be helpful if you showed us what was in `bg` after these cases rather than just a color description.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from within the points function?  I don't think I made it clear that all of the bg commands I tried were from within the points function.

Comment: And I just realized that all of the bg attempts shown are for a slightly different data set, one that didn't need subsetting.  In any case, Michael Hoffmann's solution worked.

Comment: No, but if you are trying to figure out a problem like this, it also helps to make an intermediate variable that you can examine directly as I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps if you provide an easily reproducible example by using something like `dput()` to show the data you are using:

```
> dput(ztestHSV)
structure(list(y = c(0L, -1L, -1L, -2L), x = c(0L, 2L, 0L, -2L
), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("m", "s"), class = "factor"), 
    colorHSV = c("0.02,0.83,0.89", "0.59,0.59,0.85", "0.25,0.45,0.8", 
    "0.55,0.41,0.8"), colorText = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("blue", 
    "green", "red", "turquoise"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("y", 
"x", "group", "colorHSV", "colorText"), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")
```

You can convert the vector of character strings into a list of numerics, and then use `do.call()` to call `hsv()` on each one, like this:

```
> bg <- sapply(strsplit(ztestHSV$colorHSV, ","), function(x) do.call(hsv, as.list(as.numeric(x))))
> dput(bg)
c("#E33D27", "#5994D9", "#9ECC70", "#78B3CC")
> plot(1:4, pch = 21, cex = 20, bg = bg)
```

Comment: I didn't know about dput.  I've added it to the original question just for completeness.  Your solution worked well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to split that one column into three separate columns, and then pass each to `hsv`. The handiest way to do that (that I know of) is to use `colsplit` from **reshape2**:

```
> hsvCols <- reshape2::colsplit(ztestHSV$colorHSV,",",names = c('h','s','v'))
> with(hsvCols,hsv(h,s,v))
[1] "#E33D27" "#5994D9" "#9ECC70" "#78B3CC"
```

And then you can assign those to `bg` and plot. Note that this saves a fair bit of typing, and having to deal with explicitly coercing values to numeric.